# Minimap causing lag

Tags: java, android, andengine

I make a minimap like this:

```
public void createMinimap() {
for (int i = 0; i < tilearray.size(); i++) {
    float tileX = (200 * tilearray.get(i).getX()) / (getmWidth() * 64);
    float tileY = (100 * tilearray.get(i).getY()) / (getmHeight() * 64);
    final Rectangle tileRect = new Rectangle(tileX + 590, tileY + 380,
        (64 * 200) / (getmWidth() * 64) + (float) 1, (64 * 100)
            / (getmHeight() * 64) + (float) 1, vbom);
    tileRect.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    tileRect.setAlpha(.7f);
    gameHUD.attachChild(tileRect);
    mapRectArray.add(tileRect);
}
}
```

And when I have lots of elements in tilearray, my game lags some. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating  more number of tiles and  Rectangle objects , it may effect  loading.So, i can suggest you to load the resources before the game launches.Load these resources in back ground by placing  loading screen.So, after loading all resources you can skip to Game